# Python confluent-kafka package return returns "Disconnected while requesting ApiVersion"

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-python

Environment
os: macOS

python library confluent_kafka==1.7.0

external kafka broker version 2.6.1

not specify any security protocol, everything is default PLAINTEXT

run this

```
from confluent_kafka import Consumer
    c = Consumer(
    {
        'group.id': 'test',
        "bootstrap.servers": "my-external-host:9092",
    }
c.list_topics()
)
```

and it doesn't work, returns me the error "Disconnected while requesting ApiVersion"

Tired to use separate tool like **Kafka tool** and another python package like **kafka-python** - and it's working, but confluent_kafka not.

debug info

> %7|1637327168.507|BROKER|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:app]: GroupCoordinator: Added new broker with NodeId -1
> %7|1637327168.507|BROKER|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:app]: my-external-host:9092/bootstrap: Added new broker with NodeId -1
> %7|1637327168.507|BRKMAIN|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: GroupCoordinator: Enter main broker thread
> %7|1637327168.507|BRKMAIN|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: Enter main broker thread
> %7|1637327168.507|INIT|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:app]: librdkafka v1.7.0 (0x10700ff) rdkafka#consumer-1 initialized (builtin.features gzip,snappy,ssl,sasl,regex,lz4,sasl_gssapi,sasl_plain,sasl_scram,plugins,zstd,sasl_oauthbearer, STRIP STATIC_LINKING CC GXX PKGCONFIG OSXLD LIBDL PLUGINS ZLIB SSL SASL_CYRUS ZSTD HDRHISTOGRAM SNAPPY SOCKEM SASL_SCRAM SASL_OAUTHBEARER CRC32C_HW, debug 0x2)
> %7|1637327168.507|CONNECT|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: my-external-host:9092/bootstrap: Selected for cluster connection: coordinator query (broker has 0 connection attempt(s))
> %7|1637327168.507|BRKMAIN|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:my-external-host:9092/bootstrap]: my-external-host:9092/bootstrap: Enter main broker thread
> %7|1637327168.507|CONNECT|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:my-external-host:9092/bootstrap]: my-external-host:9092/bootstrap: Received CONNECT op
> %7|1637327168.507|STATE|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:my-external-host:9092/bootstrap]: my-external-host:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state INIT -> TRY_CONNECT
> %7|1637327168.507|CONNECT|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 49ms: application metadata request
> %7|1637327168.507|CONNECT|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 49ms: application metadata request
> %7|1637327168.507|CONNECT|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:my-external-host:9092/bootstrap]: my-external-host:9092/bootstrap: broker in state TRY_CONNECT connecting
> %7|1637327168.507|STATE|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:my-external-host:9092/bootstrap]: my-external-host:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state TRY_CONNECT -> CONNECT
> %7|1637327168.507|CONNECT|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:app]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection: still suppressed for 49ms: application metadata request
> %7|1637327168.509|CONNECT|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:my-external-host:9092/bootstrap]: my-external-host:9092/bootstrap: Connecting to ipv4#10.103.68.24:9092 (plaintext) with socket 11
> %7|1637327168.578|CONNECT|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:my-external-host:9092/bootstrap]: my-external-host:9092/bootstrap: Connected to ipv4#10.103.68.24:9092
> %7|1637327168.578|CONNECTED|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:my-external-host:9092/bootstrap]: my-external-host:9092/bootstrap: Connected (#1)
> %7|1637327168.578|FEATURE|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:my-external-host:9092/bootstrap]: my-external-host:9092/bootstrap: Updated enabled protocol features +ApiVersion to ApiVersion
> %7|1637327168.578|STATE|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:my-external-host:9092/bootstrap]: my-external-host:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state CONNECT -> APIVERSION_QUERY
> %7|1637327168.578|CONNECT|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:app]: Cluster connection already in progress: application metadata request
> %7|1637327168.580|FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:my-external-host:9092/bootstrap]: my-external-host:9092/bootstrap: Disconnected while requesting ApiVersion: might be caused by incorrect security.protocol configuration (connecting to a SSL listener?) or broker version is < 0.10 (see api.version.request) (after 2ms in state APIVERSION_QUERY) (_TRANSPORT)
> %6|1637327168.580|FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:my-external-host:9092/bootstrap]: my-external-host:9092/bootstrap: Disconnected while requesting ApiVersion: might be caused by incorrect security.protocol configuration (connecting to a SSL listener?) or broker version is < 0.10 (see api.version.request) (after 2ms in state APIVERSION_QUERY)
> %7|1637327168.580|FEATURE|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:my-external-host:9092/bootstrap]: my-external-host:9092/bootstrap: Updated enabled protocol features -ApiVersion to
> %7|1637327168.580|STATE|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:my-external-host:9092/bootstrap]: my-external-host:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state APIVERSION_QUERY -> DOWN